# SSL error on WSO2 Data Analytics Server

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, wso2-das

I am running wso2 Data Analytics Server, I had some error like the line below in DAS log file

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <192.168.3.27> != localhost
```

when I entered my created dashboard I couldn't see any data and dashboard was empty until I have done what [this link](http://udarakr.blogspot.com/2014/04/you-may-get-following-error-and-your.html) said and the problem did not happen again on DAS dashboard **BUT** when I want to connect API Manager to DAS I got some error on `admin-dashboard` in the `Configure Analytics` menu. I couldn't save the config and I got an error like this on `API Manager`:

> Error occurred while deploying artifacts (Cause:org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

I have no error on `DAS` dashboard but I can not connect `AM` to `DAS`. Any Idea?

Comment: This error occur because of you do not have CA signed certificate. What you have to do to get rid of this is add your certificate in to client-truststore.jks and wso2carbon.jks of wso2carbon server. And also check your default java key store whether it has the certificate that you are using imported. And can i know that whether you are using a LB or not? Because you have to add this certificate to the LB also.

Answer (score 0):

Your current certificate, stored inside wso2carbon.jks, point to localhost, but if you  deployed your solution in different servers you need to create a .jks for each server with the CN=server IP or full server hostname. 
In the client-truststore.jks you need to store the certificates of each server you need to connect.

Comment: did I understand it right? I have to add my IP to wso2carbon.jks like this: `keytool -genkeypair -alias 10.10.60.100-keyalg RSA -keystore wso2carbon.jks` and what should I do with client-truststore.jks??

Comment: When you run that command in a command line the keytool ask you to introduce some information. The first one is the CN and must be the server IP or the full server name. The error show that you use 192.168.3.27 as the server IP. In the client-truststore.jks you need to store the certificate of the other servers.

Comment: I have about 15 VMs connected to my DAS. They all publish data to DAS correctly and without any problem, I didn't add their CA to DAS client-truststore.jks at first place and they are working, I should add them due to my new CN? @jorge-infante-osorio

Answer (score 0):

You are getting host name verification error,because the domain name in the url and CN name in the public certificates are not matched. Proper solution is to have the CN name to match the domain name of the url.

if you want to skip the hostname verification then 
, modify the axis2.xml(**https - transportSender**) to turn Hostname Verification off as below.

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```